# Same prediction result with little probabilities change

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing, probability, training-datasets, random-forests

I built a job prediction system leveraging data scrapped from LinkedIn with Random Forest and compared it to XGBoost. XGBoost was used due to its high accuracy after training.

When I made a prediction, I always obtained nearly similar results every time. There is only a slight difference in the probability percentage.

This same goes for the Random Forest.

Does this problem occur due to my bad dataset?

I took a list of skills and years of experience for the user input. My data has about 20k points after done data cleaning.